# Swift - Calendar date 1 inSameDayAs date 2 for dictionary of dates timestamps which returns array of only one date and how much times is repeating

Tags: swift, date, dictionary, timestamp

I have `[Int64:[String:String]]` where Int64 is time stamp.
How to detect and remove same day dates where one of the arguments in the `[String:String]` is `["name"] = "test"` and repeats multiple times and also to add in the dictionary how much `["times"]` is repeating.

Example `[Int64:[String:String]]`

```
    [1543058992:["name:"test"], 1543058988:["name:"test"],
     1543058990:["name:"test"], 1543058984:["name:"test2"],
     1543945308:["name:"test2"], 1543945208:["name:"test2]",
     1550058984:["name:"test3"]]
```

Expected `[Int64:[String:String]]` after processing:

```
    [1543058992: ["name:"test", "times":"3"],
     1543058993: ["name:"test2", "times":"1"],
     1543945308: ["name:"test2", "times":"2"],
     1550058984: ["name:"test3"]]
```

Comment: I can think of one solution but it requires that the resulting timestamp keys be midnight for the given day. Is that acceptable?

Comment: And what timezone should your idea of "same day" be based on? UTC? The user's local timezone? Some other specific timezone?

Comment: iCloud time zone which is user local timezone. Doesn't matter it has to match the same day.

Comment: Please update your question with what you have attempted so far. Clearly explain what issues you are having.

Comment: I've not attempted yet, because I will type more than 100 lines of code. I know that this can be typed in less than 20 lines. That's why I'm asking here for clear solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import Foundation
typealias YourDict = [Int64: [String: String]]
let initial: YourDict = [
    1543058992: ["name": "test"],
    1543058988: ["name": "test"],
    1543058990: ["name": "test"],
    1543058984: ["name": "test"],
    1543945308: ["name": "test2"],
    1543945208: ["name": "test2"],
    1550058984: ["name": "test3"]
]

var result: YourDict = [:]
let calendar = Calendar.current
initial.forEach { item in
    let key = item.key
    let currentValueDict = item.value
    var foundCheckingKey: Int64?
    let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(key * 1000))
    if result.contains(where: { checkingItem in
        let checkingKey = checkingItem.key
        foundCheckingKey = checkingKey
        let checkingDate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(checkingKey * 1000))
        return calendar.isDate(date, inSameDayAs: checkingDate)
    }) {
        let previousCount = Int(result[foundCheckingKey!]!["times"]!)!
        result[foundCheckingKey!]!["times"] = "\(previousCount + 1)"
    } else {
        result[key] = ["name": currentValueDict["name"]!, "times": "1"]
    }
}
print(result)
```

Comment: Yes, @rmaddy is right. I don't have repeating time stamps and also I need to combine in 1 dict the day X and count how much times the day X is repeated and add the repeats(times) in the same dict.